# Debian Unstable + Postfix 2.6.5 + dkim-filter 2.8.2 issue

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, dkim

I have Postfix installed on Debian Unstable, as the title states, the system is completely up-to-date, I have tried to get DKIM signatures working on outgoing mail using dkim-filter 2.8.2.

I couldn't use the default Debian way of doing things with sockets, instead I used the Ubuntu way:

> SOCKET="inet:12345@localhost"`

I have the following in my postfix/main.cf

> milter_default_action = accept
>   milter_protocol = 6
>   smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12345
>   non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12345

All is fine except I get the following message I start DKIM in mail.log:

> dkim-filter[22029]: can't configure DKIM library; continuing

And when it tries to sign mails I get the following error:

> postfix/cleanup[22042]: warning: milter inet:localhost:12345: can't read SMFIC_EOH reply packet header: Success

And then dkim-filter daemon stops.

I've looked through Google but found no actual way to fix this that works for me. I have this working fine on an Ubuntu server but would love to get it working on Debian too.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I switched to opendkim which actually works.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer.